# PHP PDO стринг иницализации, передача пустого пароля

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Добрый день. Обьясните, пожалуйста новичку. Совсем запутался в кавычках. Вот так работает:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3310;dbname=gallery', 'root', '', [PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]);
```

а вот так нет:

```
const dbname = 'gallery';
const host = '127.0.0.1';
const port='3310';
const dbuser = 'root';
const dbpassword = '';
const pdo_options = '[PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC]';

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.host.';port='.port.';dbname='.dbname.','.dbuser.','.dbpassword.','.pdo_options);

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\gallerymvc\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\gallerymvc\index.php(5): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....') #1 {main} thrown in D:\PHP\OSPanel\domains\gallerymvc\index.php on line 5
```

Как-то пустой пароль не получается через константу передать, я так понимаю. Буду рад любому ответу. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в конструктор PDO передать одним аргументом все `'mysql:host='.host.';port='.port.';dbname='.dbname.','.dbuser.','.dbpassword.','.pdo_options`, а должны передать 4 аргумента. Юзера, пароль и опции не надо в строку к первому аргументу присоединять.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!) Итого правильная строчка выглядит так: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.host.';port='.port.';dbname='.dbname, dbuser, dbpassword, pdo_options);